# Find case insensitive word or sentence in a body of text - PHP

Tags: php

I am a complete newbie in PHP and programming generally. I am looking for an example or function of searching a sentence or a word in a body of text.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example below.

```
<?php
    $textYouAreSearchingFor = "vestibulum";

    $fullBody = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget tempus lorem. Donec sagittis massa dui, sed consequat eros suscipit quis. Curabitur accumsan tortor eu vulputate volutpat. Ut accumsan odio justo, vitae semper nunc tristique sed. Pellentesque sit amet leo bibendum, finibus metus a, elementum tortor. Etiam finibus efficitur ligula ac vulputate. Proin vitae tristique arcu. Curabitur vestibulum libero ante, gravida blandit tortor gravida in. Curabitur tincidunt rhoncus nisi in mattis. Phasellus fermentum magna eu nibh aliquet, non sagittis erat tem ....';

    if(stristr($fullBody, $textYouAreSearchingFor) !== FALSE) {
        echo "Hey, we found '{$textYouAreSearchingFor}' in full body text";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to find the position of a text string inside another text string.

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$word = "quick";
$text_position = strpos($text, $word);
# $text_position is 4
```